# DuckDB python API: query composition

Tags: python, duckdb

Suppose I use DuckDB with python, for querying an Apache parquet file `test.pq` with a table containing two columns `f1` and `f2`.

```
r1 = duckdb.query("""
SELECT f1 FROM parquet_scan('test.pq') WHERE f2 > 1
""")
```

Now I would like to use `r1` result in another query, like:

```
duckdb.query("""SELECT * FROM r1 WHERE f1 > 10""")
```

However, last instruction gives: `RuntimeError: Catalog Error: Table with name r1 does not exist!`

Am I missing a DuckDB method equivalent to Apache Spark `registerTempTable()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
r1 = duckdb.query("""
SELECT f1 FROM parquet_scan('test.pq') WHERE f2 > 1
""")
```

Does not create a table called r1, but actually creates a relation that is nothing else than an execution plan. Hence if you call an execute on that, would actually execute a query that scans the parquet file

```py
result = r1.execute()
```

If you want to query it as a table, you basically have two options.

1. You create a view from your relation

```py
r1.create_view('table_name')
```

2. You change your SQL query to create a duckdb table

```py
conn = duckdb.connect()
conn.execute("create table t as SELECT f1 FROM parquet_scan('test.pq') where f2 > 1 ")
```

Note that in 1 you will actually load the parquet data to a Duck table, while with 2 you will be constantly reading the parquet data itself.

Finally, if you just want to stack up filters, then you could do:

```py
r2 = r1.filter("f1>10")
```

There is more info on the Python Relational Api on Duckdb's website, more specifically at:
https://duckdb.org/docs/api/python

https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/blob/master/examples/python/duckdb-python.py

Hopefully, that was helpful! ;-)

Comment: Isn't it exactly the other way around, creating a view as in 1 will read the parquet again and again for each query, and 2 will create and in-memory duckdb table and query that? Otherwise, this would completely counter to the intuition I have for a "view".